Record PCM Audio in HEVC video in an iOS app
Is it possible to set AVCaptureMovieFileOutput to record the audio for my HECV video as 44100Hz 16 bit mono PCM. If yes: how does it work?
I want to do some post processing on the audio after recording. I am aware, that I could record audio and video separately but for reasons this is not an option in my case.
Thank you in advance
